# how to choose printer in emacs on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, bash, emacs

I am new to both emacs and also do not have much experience with bash. I have a few questions which are related?

(1) Can I set up emacs such that I can choose the printer that I print to? I have access to one printer connected by USB and two network printers and I do not always want to print to the same printer.

(2) How do I find out the exact names of these printers (required for setup with emacs)? Are these the same as the names that show up in `System Preferences -> Print & Fax` on Mac OSX

(3) Is there a command or something to find the names of printers (connected by USB and network printers) that one has access to?

Thanks to all the experts here, who are always so helpful.

Comment: I appreciate why many are voting to close this question. Can I appeal on behalf of the author? Programming tools are essential to our day-to-day lives as developers. Here we have a programmer looking for help with a tool... suggest alternate sites by all means, but since programmers.stackexchange.com isn't an option when you hit the "close" link and select "off topic", and superusers is a silly suggestion for an emacs question, I'd really love an answer here. I myself always search SO first when I have an emacs question.

Answer (score 2):

Running `lpq` in a terminal should show you what printers are available on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, `lpq` does not work. When I type it, it just returns AdobePDF9. However my computer is connected to another printer via USB at this moment. In addition, I can print on two network printers from here.

Comment: Huh. They can buy CUPS but they can't get it right...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: Apple purchased CUPS (the printing subsystem used in OS X and various other *nices) from its original developers a while ago, so you'd think that they'd be able to get it to show all the printers the system has configured.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used custom emacs variables like `lpr-printer-switch` or `printer-name`. And I'm not sure you can *select* a different printer than the default from inside emacs.

But you can

```
lpstat -p -d  # list known printers
lpoptions -d PRINTER  # change the default printer
```

So you need CUPS properly configured. I usually go to http://localhost:631/.
Not sure for OSX, but at least this works on Linux.